# Pins of GPIO expander 'MCP23017' randomly turning on when connected to multiple motor drivers powering 3V dc motors

Tags: gpio, dc-motor, adafruit, circuitpython

I have a [MCP23017](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/*20001952c.pdf*) GPIO expander connected to four [DRV8833](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8833.pdf?ts=1635317290471&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) dual channel Motor drivers. This setup is later meant to drive eight motors concurrently. I tried testing a few patterns and noticed that sometimes when I set the pins on and off in small time increments (~0.005s) after a seemingly random amount of time (either immediately or after ~100+ iterations) the MCP has random pinvalues set to True which I never touched. This random fluctuation makes it very difficult to reliably control the motors.

Here is what the simplified sourcecode looks like

```
import board
import busio
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017 import MCP23017
from time import sleep
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp = MCP23017(i2c)
pins = []
for i in range(15):
    pin = mcp.get_pin(i)
    pin.switch_to_output()
    pins.append(pin)

while True:
    pins[1].value = True
    pins[3].value = True
    running_motors=[(a,i.value) for a,i in enumerate(pins) if i.value]
    if len(running_motors)>2:
        raise
    sleep(0.001)
    pins[1].value = False
    pins[2].value = True
    pins[3].value = False
    pins[4].value = True
    sleep(0.001)
    pins[2].value = False
    pins[4].value = False
    sleep(0.5)
```

At first, `running_motors` only contains the values `[(1, True), (3, True)]`. However, after ~100-300 iterations suddenly it prints out `[(0, True), (1, True), (3, True)]`.

This problem does not occur when no motors are connected to the motor drivers. I am using drone motors such as [these ones](https://www.amazon.de/ViaGasaFamido-RPM-50000-Hohlschale-Coreless-Quadcopter/dp/B07Z3XBPDS/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=3v%20drone%20motor&qid=1628187888&sr=8-5) with this setup. I read through the datasheets of both chips but was unable to figure out what may be causing this error, but I have no prior experience with electrical engineering.

Comment: You can troubleshoot in two steps: (1) Instead of MCP23017, use Rpi GPIO pins to control the DC motor driver, Only when you find everything OK, then you swap Rpi GPIO with MCP23017 GPIO. (2) Instead of DRV8833, use L298N instead. Only if you find everythin OK, then you swap L298N with DRV8833. (3) Use low speed, geared DC motor , eg TT130 tyoe for testing.  Only everything OK., then swap TT130 with high speed drone motors.